# How to retrieve all pendingIntent created that has yet to be cancelled?

Tags: android, android-pendingintent

Reading from https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent

> A PendingIntent itself is simply a reference to a token maintained by
> the system describing the original data used to retrieve it. This
> means that even if its owning application's process is killed, the
> PendingIntent itself will remain usable from other processes that have
> been given it.

I understand that Pending Intent stays there forever as long as the Application is not deleted.

If I previously created pendingIntent using a System Time as code

```
        PendingIntent detailPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
            context,
            (int) System.currentTimeMillis(),
            detailIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
        );
```

There will be many of them created! I am hoping to retrieve them and remove them.
How can I do that? (I cannot get back the code)

Comment: What are you doing with these `PendingIntent`s?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `PendingIntent` that you need to remove without knowing its request code, you can't directly remove it because `PendingIntent` doesn't expose methods to cancel like this. However, you can use the following approach to work around this issue:

1. **Create a New Intent:** Create a new `Intent` that is identical to the one used in original `PendingIntent`. Ensure that all the intent data, action, and extras are the same.
2. **Create a New PendingIntent:** Create a new `PendingIntent` with the same `Intent` that you created in step 1 but with a known request code.
3. **Cancel the New PendingIntent:** You can now use this new `PendingIntent` to cancel it.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score 0):

`PendingIntent`s don't **"stay there forever"**. A `PendingIntent` will only hang around in the system if there is a reference to it. So if you've created `PendingIntent`s and handed them off to `AlarmManager` or a `Notification` or some other app, they will not be deleted. But if you've created `PendingIntent`s and not passed them to other apps (or saved a reference to them in your own app) then they will be deleted. Also, if the `PendingIntent` is no longer held by `AlarmManager` or `Notification` (because you've canceled or triggered the alarm or the `Notification` has been removed) then Android will also delete it.